# $f(x^2+yf(x))=xf(x+y)$.Find f

Tags: functional-equations

> Find all real functions $f:R\mapsto R$ satisfying the relation   $$f(x^2+yf(x))=xf(x+y).$$

**My Answer**: Putting $y=0$ we get,
$f(x^2)=xf(x)$. o

Which implies $\frac{f(x^2)}{x^2}=\frac{f(x)}{x}$.

Let $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}$.(Assume $x\ne 0$)

Hence, $g(x)=g(x^2)$.

Therefore, $g(x)=c$, Or $f(x)=cx$ (when $x \ne 0$)

And $f(0)=0$ (By putting $x=y=0$).

Is my answer is ask right?? If not then kindly tell me the mistake!

Comment: How do you go from $g(x) = g(x^2)$ so $g(x) = c$? For example, take $g(x) = 1$ if $x = 0$ and $g(x) = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: Hint : show that $f$ is odd function and $f(0) = 0$

Comment: @Evan William Chandra Then what to do ??

Comment: $g(x)=g(x^2)$ only shows that $g$ has a single value on sets of the form $\{ a^{2^n} \mid n \in \mathbb Z \}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $f$ is not identically 0 then prove that $f(x)=0$ if and only if $x$ is 0. Then show that $f(x^2-xf(x))=xf(0)=0$. Thus $f(x)=x$.

Comment: How do you show that $f(x)=0$ implies $x=0$?

Comment: How? $f(x^2+yf(x))=c(x^2+ycx)=cx^2+c^2xy$ on the other hand $xf(x+y)=cx(x+y)$. Am I missing something?

Comment: If $c$ is a zero show that for any real number $r$ , $f(rc)=0$ thus $f$ is identically 0.